# How to recognise Full House and Two pair in a javascript poker game

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to create a Dice Poker game in Javascript. The last 24 hours I have been trying to create a function that recognises the Full House(2 of the same value and 3 of the same value) and the two pair. The other hands work fine.

So far I just can't seem to figure it out. Below is the code I have so far:

```
const resultLogic = {
    fiveOfAKind: () => {
        for(let i = 0; i <= 1; i++){
            let count = 1;
            for(let j = i + 1; j < diceArray.length; j++){
               if(diceArray[i] == diceArray[j])
                 count++;
           }
            if(count == 5)
             return true;
          }
           return false;
    },
    fourOfAKind: () => {
            for(let i = 0; i <= 1; i++){
              let count = 1;
              for(let j = i + 1; j < diceArray.length; j++){
                 if(diceArray[i]==diceArray[j])
                   count++;
             }
              if(count == 4)
               return true;
            }
             return false;
    },
    fullHouse: () => {
        return false;
        // if threeOfAKind === true && pair === true
    },
    sixHighStraight: () => {
        // if diceArr === 2,3,4,5,6. There should always be a 6, never a 1 and every dice should be different
        if (diceArray.includes(2) && diceArray.includes(3) && diceArray.includes(4) && diceArray.includes(5) && diceArray.includes(6)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
    fiveHighStraight: () => {
        // if diceArr === 1,2,3,4,5. There should never be a 6 and every dice should be different
        if (diceArray.includes(1) && diceArray.includes(2) && diceArray.includes(3) && diceArray.includes(4) && diceArray.includes(5)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
    threeOfAKind: () => {
        for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            let count = 1;
            for (let j = i + 1; j < diceArray.length; j++) {
                if (diceArray[i] == diceArray[j])
                    count++;
            }
            if (count == 3)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
    twoPair: () => {
        // for (var i = 0; i < diceArray.length; i++) {
        //     var count = 1;
        //     var pairs = 0;
        //     for (var j = i + 1; j < diceArray.length; j++) {
        //         if (diceArray[i] == diceArray[j])
        //             count++;
        //     }
        //     if (count == 2) {
        //         pairs++;
        //         let firstPair = [];
        //         console.log(diceArray);
        //         console.log(`i = ${i} j = ${j}`);
        //         return true;   
        //     }
        // }
        return false;
    }
        // // if diceArr contains pair x 2
        //     for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        //         var count = 1;
        //         for (var j = i + 1; j < diceArray.length; j++) {
        //             if (diceArray[i] == diceArray[j])
        //                 count++;
        //         } if (count == 2) {
        //             count = 0;
        //             console.log(diceArray);

        //             diceArray.splice(i, i + 1) && diceArray.splice(j, j + 1);
        //             console.log(diceArray);
        //             for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        //                 var count = 1;
        //                 for (var j = i + 1; j < diceArray.length; j++) {
        //                     if (diceArray[i] == diceArray[j])
        //                         count++;
        //                 } if (count == 2) {
        //                     return true;
        //                 }

        //             }
        //             return false;
        //         }
        //     }
        // return false;
    // }
    ,
    pair: () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < diceArray.length; i++) {
            let count = 1;
            for (let j = i + 1; j < diceArray.length; j++) {
                if (diceArray[i] == diceArray[j])
                    count++;
            }
            if (count == 2)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Code that has been commented out have been unsuccesfull attempts.

Hopefully someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object which holds the count of each of the value.

```js
//To check full house
const fullHouse = (arr) => {
  let countObj = {}
  for(let x of arr){
    countObj[x] = (countObj[x] || 0) + 1;
  }
  let vals = Object.values(countObj);
  if((vals[0] === 2 && vals[1] === 3) || (vals[1] === 2 && vals[0] === 3)){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

//To check two pairs
const twoPairs = arr => {
  let countObj = {}
  for(let x of arr){
    countObj[x] = (countObj[x] || 0) + 1;
  }
  let vals = Object.values(countObj);
  //console.log(vals);
  if(vals.filter(x => x === 2).length == 2) return true;
  return false;
}


//To test the code
let arrays = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 4, 2, 4, 2], [2, 2, 4, 4, 6]]
arrays.forEach(x => {
  console.log(`Array: ${JSON.stringify(x)}`)
  console.log(`Full House: ${fullHouse(x)}`)
  console.log(`Two Pairs: ${twoPairs(x)}`)
})
```